# Which one is used more widely for "Jump" in software interfaces : "Sprung" or "springen"

Tags: english-to-german, software

I know that I can directly use the english word but I'm trying to use generally accepted and agreed german terms in the german translation of our software. Our developers missed some of the button strings when we sent them to translation and I'm stuck with the translation of "Jump".

The second part of my question is if I should use the noun forms or the verb forms for button strings like "Jump", "End", "Start" etc. Which one is common in german? The german translator from the translation company seems to be confused about this matter because they used both forms for them. I can separate this part from my question if you think that this should be a separate question.

Comment: *Sprung* is the actual leap, while *springen* is the act of leaping. But you should give a more complete example. What does the "Jump"-button actually do?

Comment: It's actually a physical button which doesn't have a soft representation on the interface :) My real intention was to find out the general way of translating button names. I'm also writing the operating manual where I need to explain those physical buttons, too. The "Jump" button does skip program steps on our industrial control panel. It's called "Jump" in the english manual.

Comment: I think "Überspringen" is used in German interfaces. PS. Why "Jump" and not standard "Skip"?

Comment: Can you give more context? Without context, nobody can provide a reasonable translation. As for nouns and verbs: Are other (similar) buttons (in German) labeled with verbs or nouns? I'd try to be consistent with that.

Comment: Sorry, but "Jump" is really not good for computer also in English, I think it is rather you made the translator going wrong, however a skilled translator should know this. "Goto", "Skip" is preferred. "Gehe zu" is probably the best generic. "Überspringen" is not used.

Comment: @Thomas: In larger applications, shortcut buttons to directly *jump* to another section of the application are a very common feature and both the word *to jump* and the word *springen* are absolutely fitting in my opinion. (However, the OP has meanwhile clarified that is not what their button does.)

Comment: Note that there is more than njust "noun forms" and "verb forms" - you could also decide between the infinitive (*springen*) and the imperative (*springe*) verb form, for example, each of which can make sense with respect to software.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer really depends on how the button actually works. There are many possibilities:

1. The button skips a defined number of steps: in that case I'd label it *Überspringen*.
2. The button jumps to a step that the user can choose: I'd label it *Gehe zu*.
3. The button jumps to a fixed step: I'd label it *Weiter* or something similar.

If the above do not fit your needs, please provide further information on what the button does.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the solutions. I'm starting to think that we did miscall this button in english. This button does end the execution of the current step and starts the next step each time it's been pressed. We did explain its function as "step jumping" in the english manual but when I tried to explain it to you yesterday I've used the term "skip" in the comments. Maybe "Skip" is more suitable for its function. I'm not sure anymore.

Comment: @Montag451 sounds like Skip => Überspringen :)

Comment: I've just remembered that we already had the manual translated to german, sorry for that. I was intensely buried into the software string translations since 2 weeks, so I had completely forgotten that we already had the manuals translated. They have choosen "Sprung-Taste" for the "Jump Button" in the manual. I'm not fully confident with this solution and the german translator because they did many problematic translations before. Does "Übersprung-Taste" sound good if I decide to transition to "Skip Button".

Comment: I would then call it *"Überspringen"-Taste*, not *Übersprung-Taste*. *Übersprung* can mean something different (for example: The act of a dog licking his b..ls if he doesn't know how to react is called a *Übersprungshandlung*).

Comment: Interestingly many online translation systems do propose "Sprung Taste" and "Überspringen Taste" as the german translation of "Skip Key". I'm going to use one of these translations. ("Sprung Taste" is already used in the german manual)

Comment: *Sprung Taste* contains a Deppenleerzeichen. It should be *Sprungtaste* or *Sprung-Taste*.